# Mod rewrite - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use urls like

> www.example.com/viewpost.php?TITLE=mp3playerforsale&ID=123

Where i am passing ID parameter and Title and then display records from sql in PHP.

Later I can able to use MOD REWRITE functionality in .htaccess and able to convert as dynamic seo friendly url like

> www.example.com/mp3playerforsale-123
>   www.example.com/carforsale-124

Where 123 gets corresponding records stored in sql database, e.g.

```
ID    Title
123   mp3playerforsale
124   carforsale
```

Now I have the requirement that I have two pages which have ID and title as parameters. But both has to displayed in two different pages.

Example:

> mp3players should go to page viewpost.php?ID=123
>   cars should go to page viewpost2.php?ID=123

When i tried both displayed in viewpost.php where I need to display cars category in different pages.

I am already using this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([-A-Za-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/? viewpost.php?TITLE=$1&ID=$2 [NC]
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Why do they have the same ID? The whole point of an ID (in general terms) is that they're unique...

Comment: yes the ID parameter is unique and and data stored on the same table.

Comment: So is `cars should go to page viewpost2.php?ID=123` a typo? Should it be `ID=124`?

Comment: If not could you show some examples of URLs and there intended destination?

Answer (score 0):

You may redirect both cases to the single page, where it will be decided which template to use by php code.

Comment: It may be a good suggestion, If the content little bit changes between two pages, but I have two entire different pages, which have some unique differences between each page, the only relation is ID parameter.
anyother suggestions ?

Comment: I meant you may decide what controller and view to apply to the request based on the ID by implementing your own routing mechanism (in terms of MVC). I think, this will be the best solution, because you should not implement your app logic within web server config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question i hope these will help you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mp3players-([0-9]+)/? viewpost.php?TITLE=mp3players&ID=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule cars-([0-9]+)/? viewpost2.php?TITLE=cars&ID=$1 [NC]
```

Or this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mp3players/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/? viewpost.php?TITLE=$1&ID=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule cars/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/? viewpost2.php?TITLE=$1&ID=$2 [NC]
```

in this your links must have a mp3players or cars prefix

like

`www.example.com/mp3players/nameofproduct-123`

`www.example.com/cars/nameofproduct-124`